# How can i make def function not display twice

Tags: python, function

When I put 'n' to stop making changes to that stats "good choice" will repeat 2 times and it will go back to charc1Stat(). I want it to stop after I put in "n". Please tell me what I'm doing wrong, I'm using IDLE Python 3.7.4.

```
    P1=input("Enter your name player 1: ")
def main():
    stats1,choice1=charc1Stat()
    Change1(choice1,stats1)
def charc1Stat():
    totalPoints=15
    defsPoints1=0
    atckPoints1=0
    while totalPoints>0:
        charc1= input("{}, choose defs and atck to add points to ( you have a total of {} left): ".format(P1, totalPoints))
        charc1=charc1.lower()
        charc1=charc1.rstrip()
        charc1=charc1.lstrip()
        if charc1 == "defs":
            d1 = eval(input("How many points do you want to add to defs?: "))
            defsPoints1+= d1
            totalPoints= totalPoints - d1
            if totalPoints<0:
                print("Enter a number that is",totalPoints,"or less")
        elif charc1 == "atck":
            a1 = eval(input("How many points do you want to add to atck?: "))
            atckPoints1 += a1
            totalPoints= totalPoints - a1
            if totalPoints<0:
                 print("Enter a number that is",totalPoints,"or less")
        else:
            print("Enter atck or defs to add points")
    stats1={"name":P1, "defense":defsPoints1, "attack":atckPoints1}
    print("{} has {} points in defs and {} points in atck.".format(stats1["name"], stats1["defense"],stats1['attack']))
    choice1= input("Do you wish to change this? [y/n]: ")
    choice1=choice1.lower()
    choice1=choice1.rstrip()
    choice1=choice1.lstrip()
    Change1(choice1,stats1)
    return stats1,choice1
def Change1(choice1,stats1):
    if choice1[0]=='y':
        stats1,choice1=charc1Stat()
    if choice1[0]=='n'
        print("good choice")
main()``
```

Comment: `d1 = eval(input(...))` If you are trying to convert to int, don't use eval: `d1 = int(input(...))`.

Comment: You can combine 4 lines into 1 with: `charc1= input(...).strip().lower()`

Comment: You see "good choice" twice because you call `Change1` twice. Once in `main()` and once at the end of `charc1Stat()`

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the **Change1()** function both in your **main()** function as well as in your **charc1Stat()** function. Remove it in either one of those and you will only get the message once:

```
P1=input("Enter your name player 1: ")
def main():
    stats1,choice1=charc1Stat()
def charc1Stat():
    totalPoints=15
    defsPoints1=0
    atckPoints1=0
    while totalPoints>0:
        charc1= input("{}, choose defs and atck to add points to ( you have a total of {} left): ".format(P1, totalPoints))
        charc1=charc1.lower()
        charc1=charc1.rstrip()
        charc1=charc1.lstrip()
        if charc1 == "defs":
            d1 = eval(input("How many points do you want to add to defs?: "))
            defsPoints1+= d1
            totalPoints= totalPoints - d1
            if totalPoints<0:
                print("Enter a number that is",totalPoints,"or less")
        elif charc1 == "atck":
            a1 = eval(input("How many points do you want to add to atck?: "))
            atckPoints1 += a1
            totalPoints= totalPoints - a1
            if totalPoints<0:
                 print("Enter a number that is",totalPoints,"or less")
        else:
            print("Enter atck or defs to add points")
    stats1={"name":P1, "defense":defsPoints1, "attack":atckPoints1}
    print("{} has {} points in defs and {} points in atck.".format(stats1["name"], stats1["defense"],stats1['attack']))
    choice1= input("Do you wish to change this? [y/n]: ")
    choice1=choice1.lower()
    choice1=choice1.rstrip()
    choice1=choice1.lstrip()
    Change1(choice1,stats1)
    return stats1,choice1

def Change1(choice1,stats1):
    if choice1[0]=='y':
        stats1,choice1=charc1Stat()
    if choice1[0]=='n':
        print("good choice")
main()
```